# How to find a plus sign in a query window of SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, find

I am using Quick Find (Ctrl + F) in a query window of SQL Server Management Studio to find a plus sign. But the text box gets red border and a blue progress indicator running on the bottom.

[image: Quick Find text box]

It works instantly to find other characters. Only the plus sign is problematic.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18358.0.

Comment: Because you're in Regex Search mode; turn regex search off.

Comment: Disable the ".*" in your search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to disable the option *Use Regular Expressions (Alt + E)*.

[image: Quick Find (Ctrl + F) text box]